# How can I get invalid users banned with fail2ban?

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I have root login and password auth off. I have a custom jail.local with perm ban time and maxrety of 1. Invalid users are not getting banned. This is what one looks like

```
Aug  8 11:36:51 TWS sshd[25058]: Invalid user haxor from IP_REDACTED port 60598
Aug  8 11:36:51 TWS sshd[25058]: Received disconnect from IP_REDACTED port 60598:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug  8 11:36:51 TWS sshd[25058]: Disconnected from invalid user haxor IP_REDACTED port 60598 [preauth]
```

It seems that the sshd.conf in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd is not picking these up therefore not banning them

Comment: Can you share the SSHD stanza from your jail.local and the contents of the sshd.conf file in filter.d? It works OK for me.

Comment: Also, note that "maxretry=1" means they get one chance before being banned the second time. When I see attempts like this it always only comes from each IP once, so I have set maxretry to 0 so they get banned on the first attempt.

Comment: You can also run `fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
` to confirm that the regex is correct in your sshd.conf file and it is correctly detecting the entries in the logs.

Comment: Hi Darren, currently at work so won’t be able to share although I can change maxretry to 0 which might solve my issue. I’ll send what I have for jail.local and sshd in filter.d once im home

Comment: Just tried to ban myself my logging in with a random user and I was not banned. Here is the output from the regex command you said to do https://paste.mmolitor.com/?090aab610854f4cd#4VgG23YkwGztP2bMYbtoPQrcU14QTFVz8G4K8j9h43Wc

Comment: So it is detecting hits (1649 matched) so you're not getting banned maybe becuase your retry window is too long.

Comment: It’s at default which is 10minutes which it gets from jail.conf this is my jail.local
[sshd]
enabled = true
bantime = -1
maxretry = 0
logpath = /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Also anyone that tries to login would have been banned by now. This is a hetzner dedicated server so its being hit 24/7 so if maxretry is 0 surely find time wouldn’t matter too much ?

Comment: yes, but you said maxretry was 1. Does it not work with 0 either?

Comment: Apparently not nope. Also fail2ban-client status sshd shows this 
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:

So surely if the filter was picking them up the filter value above would have some values in it?